# How exactly does Realm() work?

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, realm

I've been using Realm for a few days now while working on a new Swift 3 iOS app, and overall, it's certainly much more pleasant to work with than CoreData.

However, the documentation doesn't appear to be detailed enough to help me figure out exactly what...

```
let realm = try! Realm()
```

...does, and whether it makes sense (or is even mandatory) to use multiple versions of this line, or if one single call is enough for the entire application.

So if anyone with thorough knowledge of Realm can help, I'd appreciate it.

My questions, in order of importance:

1. What exactly does the above line of code do? Does it open some kind of file manager stream that will then allow my application to write and read to/from Realm data files as long as the application remains running?
2. Or do I need to use this line before every Realm read/write operation? Or is it something in between the two extremes, such as needing to be called in every separate class/view controller but not before every read/write action?
3. Why does Realm use `try!` with all its methods? Is that just for purposes of simplified demonstration in the various tutorials and example source files? Or are we actually meant to suppress errors like that in production when using Realm?

Would appreciate any and all input, as the Realm documentation and example files don't seem to provide answers to these questions, unless I'm blind, which is a possibility, so I'm open to being pointed to relevant documentation/reference pages where applicable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for using Realm! We'll look into making the documentation clearer. In the meantime:

1. That line of code gives you an instance of a Realm, `realm`. In particular, `Realm()` gives you the *default Realm*, which is simply the Realm whose configuration is specified using the default configuration object. (The intention is that if your app just has one Realm, you can simply use this API to get a reference to it without having to explicitly pass in a configuration struct.) You can either call APIs on this instance like with any other Swift object, or pass it into other APIs that require a `Realm` argument.
2. Use the `realm` instance just like a normal object, don't worry about streams or any other hidden state. The only restriction is that you shouldn't pass `Realm` instances between threads or queues.
3. `try!` in our documentation is primarily for brevity. Whether a production app needs to avoid using `try!` depends on whether it can be reasonably expected to recover from a failed attempt to open a Realm, and whether special behavior needs to occur if a Realm fails to open. You can see the possible errors [here](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Realm/Error.html).

A final note: there is an important distinction between a Realm (which is the on-disk database), and instances of the `Realm` class in Swift. Multiple `Realm` instances may refer to the same underlying Realm database, if they were created with the same configuration value. For example, you might have multiple `Realm` instances in different parts of your app, or on different threads (to respect the same-thread requirement described above). Some of our users choose to create a 'manager' singleton object that opens a particular Realm at startup, handles any errors that might occur, and vends out the `Realm` instance to UI code that might need to read or write from the database. Whether this pattern is right for you depends on your coding style and the specific needs of your app, of course.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Base on my knowledge, might not really correct:

1. That line of code will create a Realm instance to control realm write/read in the current thread, in this case you are calling to the Realm with default configuration, you can modify the configuration if you need another config like database name, path,...
2. You dont need as long as you created it in your current class or just use the default Realm(), means you still need it, but can just make it class variable or something
3. `try` means it can throw error that you can handle if you want, using `try!` mean you skip the error, if you want to handle it, combine with `do` and `catch` to handle if the error happen